# How do I use the value of an object in a formula in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to first store the column number of the address of a cell containing a particular string (the date of the transaction in the format mm/dd/yyyy).

Then I want to use that column number in formula to be written in another cell. Here's my code:

```vb
tDateCol = Range("1:1").Find("Transaction Initiation Date").Column

Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=Date(Right(RC[tDateCol],4),Left(RC[tDateCol],2),Mid(RC[tDateCol],4,2))"
```

Can't get it to work.  I've even tried putting `RC[" & tDateCol & "]` but still won't work!

Comment: You could use `Match()` and do the whole thing on the formula?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in VBA if preferred over formulas.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("1:1").Find("Transaction Initiation Date")
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        tDateCol = c.Column - Selection.Column ' It's just a guess w/o tested
        Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=Date(Right(RC[" & tDateCol & "],4),Left(RC[" & tDateCol & "],2),Mid(RC[" & tDateCol & "],4,2))"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Success !  It worked.  Thanks a mil !

Answer (score 0):

In a formula:

```
=LET(x,MATCH("Transaction Initiation Date",1:1,0),
     dt,OFFSET(A1,ROW()-1,x-1), 
     DATE(RIGHT(dt,4),LEFT(dt,2),MID(dt,4,2)))
```